# Permission Denied in Batch File for FFMPEG -- Windows

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, permissions, batch

I am trying to use FFMPEG to resize a video. I want to do this with ease repeatedly, so I tried to create a batch file (I'm using Windows command line), similar to previous ones which I've successfully made.
This is the set-up.

> I have a file, call is `z.mov`.
>   I want to resize it to some generic size.
>   The following command works perfectly:
>   `ffmpeg -i z.mov -c:v libx264 -s:v 1920x1080 -c:a copy zz.mov`.

Now I want to create a batch file, and so wrote this.

```
set filename = %1
set filetype = %2
set size = %3
ffmpeg -i %filename%.%filetype% -c:v libx264 -s:v %size% -c:a copy zz.mov
exit /b
```

Of course, ideally the output would be a variable too. I would like
`output = %filename%_%size%.%filetype%`. However, I couldn't get the simpler version above to work, so I gave the simpler example above.

However, I get a "permission denied error" -- see picture below.
I've tried changing `%filename%` to `%1`; didn't change anything.
Similarly, I took away the variables, and just wrote `set filename = z`, etc; didn't change anything.
If I put the first code listed above in the batch file, then that part runs successfully.

This happens whether I run in an admin-elevated CMD window or not.

Any help on this would be most appreciated!

[image: Error Message]

Comment: To ask the obvious, have you already tried running it from command prompt that is admin elevated too i.e. Run As Administrator?

Comment: I have. It doesn't change anything. This would have been good information to include, though, so I have just put it in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turns out the antivirus was blocking WinFF/ffmpeg. Once I deactivated antivirus (Avast!), WinFF works correctly.

Comment: To be fair, I think we aren't reading beyond "I have same problem".  I almost downvoted for the same reason as the comments.  But I believe the the poster really meant "I had the same problem", because they do then go on to detail what they did to fix it.  It's a answer, not a question/comment, IMHO.  Poorly worded, in need of editing, and *probably* not the *right* answer, but an answer, nonetheless.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - It’s a comment.  A single sentence does not make an answer.  This question deserves more than a vague single sentence without any explanation at all.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 64-bit. ffmpeg v.3.4

It does not make any sense but it solved my "permission denied" and "file does not exist" errors: Use full path for infile and outfile.  The only thing I was not doing was running the batch in the same directory as the files I wanted to work on.  I was using pushd and relative paths and the batch would not work until I changed relative paths to absolute paths.  I am using the pushd / %cd% example below.  l leave it to you to find out if running the batch in the same directory as the files you are working on, w/o using infile/outfile full paths solves your problem.  Run your batch in a window with admin privileges.

```
START "" /min "%windir%\ffmpeg.exe.lnk" -y -i "%zdoc1%\_RadioRecordings\bbc13.mp3" -metadata title="BBC RADIO 1" -metadata artist="HITS. NEW MUSIC." -metadata album="bbc.co.uk/sounds" -metadata album_artist="HITS. NEW MUSIC." -ss 00:01:15 -c copy "%zdoc1%\_RadioRecordings\bbc1.mp3"
```

Or use pushd and %cd%:

```
pushd "%zdoc1%\_RadioRecordings"
START "" /min "%windir%\ffmpeg.exe.lnk" -y -i "%cd%\bbc13.mp3" -metadata title="BBC RADIO 1" -metadata artist="HITS. NEW MUSIC." -metadata album="bbc.co.uk/sounds" -metadata album_artist="HITS. NEW MUSIC." -ss 00:01:15 -c copy "%cd%\bbc1.mp3"
```

If you are running your batch as a scheduled task run the following command before your batch:

```
 taskkill /f /im conhost.exe
```

If a batch file does not finish properly an instance of conhost.exe might be left running. If you run the batch before killing conhost.exe the batch will fail.

If you are redirecting the output of your batch that is not causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm away at the moment, so can't test. But I shall test shortly!